# .net ASP.NET Web API and Knockout.js issue with returned data

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing with ASP.net Web API and knockout.js.  Basically I'm just taking this:

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail

and just using web api for the backend. So far I have everything going except for actually displaying data. I keep getting a:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: mails is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: mails
```

So before someone asks "Well is it defined?", no it's not because look at the tutorial (better picture of it here):

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PKDdG/

There is no "mails" defined anywhere. So it has to be something with how data is returned from Web API. Next question is: "Are you returning JSON?", why yes yes I am:

```
 [{"id":1,"folder":"Index","from":"Ronald.McDonald@mcdonalds.com","to":"grimace@mcdonalds.com","date":"05/29/2013","subject":"Someone stole the hamburgers","messageContent":"I believe we have a thief in the mix.  We need to check hamburglars pockets"}]
```

So if anyone has any idea on what might be going on here I'm up for constructive suggestions. :)

As requested:

```
Sammy(function () {
   this.get('#:folder', function () {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenMailData(null);
        $.get("api/mails", { folder: this.params.folder }, function (data) {
            self.chosenFolderData({ mails: data });
        });
    });

    this.get('#:folder/:mailId', function () {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenFolderData(null);
        $.get("api/mails", { mailId: this.params.mailId }, self.chosenMailData);
    });

    this.get('', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#Inbox') });
}).run();
};
```

Comment: In the linked sample `mails` was defined in `success: function(data) {
                    self.chosenFolderData({ mails: fakeData[folder] });
                }`... Can you post some of your own code how is it look like now?

Comment: Nice catch I didn't even see that, but the tutorial is actually spelled out a little different. Look at section 5 of the actual tutorial.  Added the piece that I basically wrote from the tutorial. not a lot different.  I wonder if I can use the $.ajax like they did in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Nevermind.. see correction in above code.

Comment: ok, but what is your question then? Is it still not working? Do you have the `data-bind="with: chosenFolderData"` in your view somewhere around the `data-bind="foreach: mails"`?

Comment: no question anymore, thanks for the point in the right direction.  The problem is the knockout.js tutorial is not complete.